# How to edit a file with SED?

Tags: docker, sed, command

I am running docker on a Virtual Machine on an Amazon AWS EC2 instance and I want to edit one file (application.properties) which lies in the following directory:

```
root@e2afc27e858e:/score-client/conf/applications.proteries
```

The docker image does not seem to contain vim/vi, nano or emacs. That's why I should edit the file with "sed".

In particular, in the application.properties file is a line called:

```
accessToken=
```

But I want to edit the file so that it says:

```
accessToken=abcd123
```

How do I edit the file in docker with SED?

Comment: Did you try `sed -i 's/accessToken=paste_your_aws_token_here/accessToken=abcd123' the_file` ?

Comment: @TedLyngmo Thanks your your helpful answer. I tried it, but I get an error again:
`root@cc19476f76af:/score-client/conf# sed -i 's/accessToken=/accessToken=abcd123'`

`sed: -e expression #1, char 63: unterminated s' command`

Comment: Instead of editing it you can copy the the updated property file to the container and then can restart the container

Comment: Can you check whether cat is installed or not

Comment: @Hashriama There is a <slash>-character missing at the end of the command. It should read `sed -i 's/accessToken=/accessToken=abcd123/'`

Comment: @Hashriama As you may have noticed by now, I forgot the ending `/`  :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the following `application.properties` example file

```ini
toto="some value"
accessToken="atoken"
pipo="other value"
bingo=1
```

the following `sed` command:

```
sed -i 's/^\(accessToken=\).*$/\1"abcd123"/' application.properties
```

gives as a result (i.e. `cat application.properties`)

```ini
toto="some value"
accessToken="abcd123"
pipo="other value"
bingo=1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -i /s/testtobechanged/textwanted/g applications.proteries
```